# Isomorphic bilinear forms over C and R.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can a bilinear form in 4 variables be isomorphic to one in 10 variables? I think only bilinear forms of the same number of variables can be isomorphic. Can someone help me with the correct result please!

Comment: What does it mean for two bilinear forms to be isomorphic?

Comment: Two bilinear forms B1 and B2 on a vector space V are said to be isomorphic or equivalent if there exists an invertible Linear map A from V to V such that B1(x,y)=B2(Ax,Ay) for every x,y in V.

Comment: Then the answer to your question is negative, because the respective bilinear forms aren't even defined on the same space.

Comment: To be more specific on Thorgott's comment, there is no such thing as an invertible linear map between 4-dimensional and 10-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Oh yes. I understand your comments. Thank you for the enlightenment.